# wordpress 3.5 sort by media category in insert media modal window

Tags: sorting, wordpress, modal-dialog, media

I use [media-categories-2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-categories-2/) plugin for sorting my media files, but i no sort my media files in page->insert media modal window and i cant find needed plugin for this. please help me

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure out how to do this as well. I've gotten as far as creating the categories myself using these snippets http://sumtips.com from  in functions.php

```
    add_action('init', 'create_media_categories');

function create_media_categories() {
$labels = array(
    'name' => 'Media Category'
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true
);

register_taxonomy('imagetype', 'attachment', $args);
}
```

Afterwards, I figured out how to create a new option in the Insert Media box:

```
function custom_media_upload_tab_name( $tabs ) {
    $newtab = array( 'tab_slug' => 'Your Tab Name' );
    return array_merge( $tabs, $newtab );
}

add_filter( 'media_upload_tabs', 'custom_media_upload_tab_name' );

function custom_media_upload_tab_content() {
    // I haven't gotten to this part yet
}
add_action( 'media_upload_tab_slug', 'custom_media_upload_tab_content' );
```

I'll update it when I figure out the next part!